# Maintain dropdownlist viewstate after postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, gridview, updatepanel

My set up:

1. I have a `GridView`, and two `DropDownList` in each `TemplateField`
   of it.
2. `GridView` is enclosed withing `Ajax` `UpdatePanel`.
3. I am populating one `DropDownList` from selection of other
   `DropDownList` using `JQuery`.

   I works fine till now. But when I submit this form I get `EventValidation` error. I have solved it by setting `EnableEventValidation` of `Page` to false. Error is gone. Fine. But I can't take selected value of `DropDownList` that was bound using `Jquery`, also populated values are gone. Seems like `ViewState` problem to me. Am I wrong? Any suggestions please?

Comment: Please show us your code ?

Comment: which code? whats unclear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not looking possible to me to tackle this in timeline so I swiched to server side binding of drop down list